# AutoHotKey - Swapping CTRL and Command/Windows keys

Tags: windows-7, mac, autohotkey, macbook-pro-retina

I'm using a macbook pro running Windows 7.

I've tried a few different scripts and none of them get me what I need. I need them to act *exactly* like their counterpart, i.e. Ctrl key acting as Windows key needs to have all the modifiers/system hotkeys work correctly - for instance:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> should open RUN
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> should show desktop
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> should switch monitors
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> should popup start menu
- <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>MouseScroll</kbd> should zoom text

... and so on.

Right now I'm working with this script:

```
*LCtrl:: Send,{LWin DOWN}
*LCtrl up:: Send,{LWin UP}

*LWin:: Send,{LCtrl DOWN}
*LWin up:: Send,{LCtrl UP}
```

Which works most of the time, but when I click Ctrl+R for the run screen it won't let me type in the run box. I'm not sure why that is.

I also tried this version but it was terrible and has lots of problems with modifiers:

```
LCtrl::Lwin
LWin:LCtrl
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way to achieve this goal (to completely swap the keys) without using any 3rd-party software at all. Windows has a built-in key scan code mapper facility. This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463447.aspx) explains how to swap `left CTRL key` with the `CAPS LOCK key`.

Scan codes for the Windows keys are `E0 5B` for the Left and `E0 5C` for the Right